# XSLT Recursion for Output Tree Generation

Tags: xslt

I have below xml and i need to convert to following xml using xslt

In the input xml i have referenced as topmost node which has subnodes as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<referenced>
  <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:getReferencesForServices</name>
  <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
  <type>
    <svc_type>flow</svc_type>
    <svc_subtype>default</svc_subtype>
  </type>
  <path/>
  <isPub>false</isPub>
  <isNotification>false</isNotification>
  <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
  <status>reference</status>
  <reference>
    <name>WmRoot/wm.server.ns.dependency:getReferenced</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;0</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:documentToXMLString</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;1</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:jkl</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;2</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlStringToXMLNode</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;3</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;4</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:ghi</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;5</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <type_name>record</type_name>
    </type>
    <path>/Service Path;1.0/signature;2;subPath;"/nodes;4;0;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo"</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>reference</status>
    <reference>
      <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>
        <type_name>record</type_name>
      </type>
      <path>/children;4;1;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</path>
      <isPub>false</isPub>
      <isNotification>false</isNotification>
      <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
      <status>recursive</status>
    </reference>
    <reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <type_name>record</type_name>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;1/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;2/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;3/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>reference</status>
    <reference>
      <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>
        <type_name>record</type_name>
      </type>
      <path>/children;4;1;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</path>
      <isPub>false</isPub>
      <isNotification>false</isNotification>
      <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
      <status>recursive</status>
    </reference>
  </reference>
  </reference>
</referenced>
```

Expected Output XML structure should be something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nodeInfo>
  <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:getReferencesForServices</name>
  <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
  <type>
    <svc_type>flow</svc_type>
    <svc_subtype>default</svc_subtype>
  </type>
  <path/>
  <isPub>false</isPub>
  <isNotification>false</isNotification>
  <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
  <status>reference</status>
  <children>
    <name>WmRoot/wm.server.ns.dependency:getReferenced</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;0</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </children>
  <children>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:documentToXMLString</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;1</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <children>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:jkl</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;2</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </children>
  <children>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlStringToXMLNode</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;3</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </children>
  <children>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;4</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </children>
  <children>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:ghi</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;5</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </children>
  <children>
    <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <type_name>record</type_name>
    </type>
    <path>/Service Path;1.0/signature;2;subPath;"/nodes;4;0;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo"</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>reference</status>
    <children>
      <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>
        <type_name>record</type_name>
      </type>
      <path>/children;4;1;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</path>
      <isPub>false</isPub>
      <isNotification>false</isNotification>
      <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
      <status>recursive</status>
    </children>
    <children>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <type_name>record</type_name>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;1/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;2/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;3/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>reference</status>
    <children>
      <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>
        <type_name>record</type_name>
      </type>
      <path>/children;4;1;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</path>
      <isPub>false</isPub>
      <isNotification>false</isNotification>
      <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
      <status>recursive</status>
    </children>
  </children>
  </children>
</nodeInfo>
```

But the criteria to obtain expected output xml is that from the value of one of the subnodes of input xml which is this section

```
<type>
    <svc_type>flow</svc_type>
    <svc_subtype>default</svc_subtype>
  </type>
```

the svc_type tag should either have value "flow" or "javaservice" only then map to Output xml structure.

How do i finetune the below xslt which does plain copy from input xml to ouput xml (Inshort all that is been done is renaming referenced to nodeInfo, and reference to children.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="referenced">
        <nodeInfo>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </nodeInfo>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="reference//type/svc_type[contains(., 'flow' or 'java')]">
        <children>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </children>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Appreciate your help on this topic.

Regards,
Nischal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform the `reference` based on the condition then put the condition into a predicate, so change `match="reference//type/svc_type[contains(., 'flow' or 'java')]` to `match="reference[type/svc_type[contains(., 'flow') or contains(., 'java')]]"`.

Comment: I am still seeing the output xml where svc_type node has value other than 'flow' or 'java' despite putting the suggested condition. I am i missing something more ?

Comment: I think expression should actually be `match="reference[type/svc_type[contains(., 'flow') or contains(., 'java')]]"` as the expression `'flow' or 'java'` is a boolean expression which gets evaluated as `'true'` in a function that expects a string parameter.

Comment: @Tim C- This works perfectly fine . But if you see there are times when <type> node has <type_name> as its subnode instead of <svc_type> for some <references>. How do we avoid choosing this in the Output xml ? match="(reference[type/svc_type[contains(., 'flow') or contains(., 'java')]]) and (reference[type/type_name[not(contains(.,'record'))]])" - This xslt will suffice ? Also i need to pull the data from reference/type/svc_type and map to children/type( omit the child node and map the value to node type in output xml) in the Output xml. Kindly advice how to do this ?

Comment: If you want an answer to a question, first you must ask the question... The thing is, there is no mention of special handling of `type_name` in your original question, so you won't get an answer that covers that case. I would recommend you either ask a new question, or edit this existing question to make this requirement clear (It is easier to read in the question, than in comments, you see). As for the "mapping", I think that almost certainly warrants a new question. Thank you!

Comment: @Tim C - I made sure i asked as a seperate Question . Kindly have a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386383/xslt-with-identity-template-with-multiple-match-condition-and-removal-of-unused. Looking forward for your help