# XSLT with Identity Template with Multiple Match Condition and Removal of unused nodes

Tags: xslt

I have below xml and i need to convert to following xml using xslt

In the input xml i have referenced as topmost node which has subnodes as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<referenced>
  <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:getReferencesForServices</name>
  <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
  <type>
    <svc_type>flow</svc_type>
    <svc_subtype>default</svc_subtype>
  </type>
  <path/>
  <isPub>false</isPub>
  <isNotification>false</isNotification>
  <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
  <status>reference</status>
  <reference>
    <name>WmRoot/wm.server.ns.dependency:getReferenced</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;0</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:documentToXMLString</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;1</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:jkl</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;2</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlStringToXMLNode</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;3</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>java</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;4</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:ghi</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <svc_type>xsltservice</svc_type>
      <svc_subtype>unknown</svc_subtype>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;5</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>resolved</status>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <type_name>record</type_name>
    </type>
    <path>/Service Path;1.0/signature;2;subPath;"/nodes;4;0;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo"</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>reference</status>
    <reference>
      <name>WxPackageTree/WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>
        <type_name>record</type_name>
      </type>
      <path>/children;4;1;WxPackageTree.doc:NodeInfo</path>
      <isPub>false</isPub>
      <isNotification>false</isNotification>
      <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
      <status>recursive</status>
    </reference>
    <reference>
    <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
    <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
    <type>
      <type_name>record</type_name>
    </type>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;1/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;2/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <path>/Flow Path;1.0/MAP;6/MAPCOPY;3/to_field;-2;subPath;"/nodeInfo;4;0;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo"</path>
    <isPub>false</isPub>
    <isNotification>false</isNotification>
    <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
    <status>reference</status>
    <reference>
      <name>PocTree/PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>
        <type_name>record</type_name>
      </type>
      <path>/children;4;1;PocTree.docs:nodeInfo</path>
      <isPub>false</isPub>
      <isNotification>false</isNotification>
      <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
      <status>recursive</status>
    </reference>
  </reference>
  </reference>
</referenced>
```

Expected Output XML structure should be something like :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <nodeInfo>
      <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:getReferencesForServices</name>
      <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
      <type>flow</type>
      <path/>
      <isPub>false</isPub>
      <isNotification>false</isNotification>
      <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
      <status>reference</status>
      <children>
        <name>WmRoot/wm.server.ns.dependency:getReferenced</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
        <type>java</type>
        <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;0</path>
        <isPub>false</isPub>
        <isNotification>false</isNotification>
        <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
        <status>resolved</status>
      </children>
      <children>
        <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:documentToXMLString</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
        <type>java</type>
        <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;1</path>
        <isPub>false</isPub>
        <isNotification>false</isNotification>
        <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
        <status>resolved</status>
      </reference>
      <children>
        <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:jkl</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>3</LOCK_STATUS>
        <type>xsltservice</type>
        <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;2</path>
        <isPub>false</isPub>
        <isNotification>false</isNotification>
        <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
        <status>resolved</status>
      </children>
      <children>
        <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlStringToXMLNode</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
        <type>java</type>
        <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;3</path>
        <isPub>false</isPub>
        <isNotification>false</isNotification>
        <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
        <status>resolved</status>
      </children>
      <children>
        <name>WmPublic/pub.xml:xmlNodeToDocument</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>2</LOCK_STATUS>
        <type>java</type>
        <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;4</path>
        <isPub>false</isPub>
        <isNotification>false</isNotification>
        <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
        <status>resolved</status>
      </children>
      <children>
        <name>PocTree/PocTree.services:ghi</name>
        <LOCK_STATUS>4</LOCK_STATUS>
        <type>xsltservice</type>
        <path>/Flow Path;1.0/INVOKE;5</path>
        <isPub>false</isPub>
        <isNotification>false</isNotification>
        <isFlowServiceDisabled>false</isFlowServiceDisabled>
        <status>resolved</status>
      </children>
    </nodeInfo>
```

But the criteria to obtain expected output xml is that from the value of one of the subnodes of input xml which is this section

```
  <type>
        <svc_type>flow</svc_type>
        <svc_subtype>default</svc_subtype>
      </type>
```

Which sometime does have a extra tag like this meaning  can have either  ,  child nodes or only .

```
 <type>
    <type_name>record</type_name>
  </type>
```

Now the expected Output XML should be designed such way that chose only those `<refrence>` tags from Input xml where `<svc_type>` has value of 'flow' or 'javaservice' or 'xsltservice' and omit those `<refrence>` tags which has `<type_name>` belonging to `<type>` parent node with any value.

Also the content of `<svc_type>` should be mapped to value of `<type>` and output xml should not contain subnodes `<svc_type>` and `<svc_subtype>` for its parent node `<type>`.

Kindly help on this topic.

Including the xslt written to achieve filtering of input XML

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="referenced">
        <nodeInfo>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </nodeInfo>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template  match="(reference[type/svc_type[contains(., 'flow') or contains(., 'java') or contains(., 'xsltservice')]]) and (reference[type/type_name[not(contains(.,'record'))]])">
        <children>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </children>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But above xslt still does not cover this part - 
 `<svc_type>` should be mapped to value of `<type>` and output xml should not contain subnodes `<svc_type>` and `<svc_subtype>` for its parent node `<type>`.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Robert - I have added the partial xslt written at end of Question  . Can you have a look and please advise ? About the Output , I am still not able to filter out those <refrence> tags which has <type_name> belonging to <type> parent node with any value plus do not know how to acheive - <svc_type> should be mapped to value of <type> and output xml should not contain subnodes <svc_type> and <svc_subtype> for its parent node <type>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reverse your logic. Instead of thinking about what nodes you wish to copy, you need to think of what you don't want to copy, and write a template to match these, and ignore them.

The identity template will then handle all the things you want to copy.

So, you say you want to include `<reference>` tags from Input xml where `<svc_type>` has a value of 'flow' or 'javaservice' or 'xsltservice'. The converse of this is that you want to exclude such `<reference>` which don't have a `<svc_type>` set to any of those three values:

```
<xsl:template match="reference[type/svc_type[not(contains(., 'flow') or contains(., 'java') or contains(., 'xsltservice'))]]" />
```

You other rule is already one about removal, so that can be done straight-forwardly without any logic reversal

```
<xsl:template match="reference[type/type_name]" priority="2" />
```

The priority is probably not needed here, unless you could have a `reference` tag which had both a `type/type_name` and a `type/svc_type`, in which case there would be a conflict between templates

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="referenced">
        <nodeInfo>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </nodeInfo>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="reference">
        <children>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </children>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="type[svc_type]">
        <type>
            <xsl:value-of select="svc_type" />
        </type>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="reference[type/svc_type[not(contains(., 'flow') or contains(., 'java') or contains(., 'xsltservice'))]]" />

    <xsl:template match="reference[type/type_name]" priority="2" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note the addition of the template to turn to handle you transformation on `svc_type` to just `type`.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine . Well i have one query which is how does priority = "2" working in tandem with the templates ?

Comment: It might not apply here, but if you had a `reference` element that had both a `type_name` and a `svc_type` not equal to "flow" or "java" then both templates would match in that case. That is considered an error in XSLT. The priority element is then needed to override the default priority, and resolve the conflict.